# Xamarin Forms WKWebView size doesn't shrink

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview, custom-renderer

I have a custom `WkWebView` where I set the `height` of the view to the size of the html content.

This works great when I initialize it, but the problem comes when I change the `source` of the `WkWebView` to a shorter html.

I've already encountered [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399897/how-to-update-custom-webview-height-request-when-content-is-shrunk/60622511#60622511) in the android version of my app and I fixed that by setting the HeightRequest to 0 before `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync`. In that way the view will always get bigger.

I tried the same thing with iOS but it keeps the highest content I had .

So for example :

If I set the source of the `WkWebView` to a html file that is 200px height and change it to a html file that is 1000px, it works fine and I can see all the content. BUT, if I try to go back to my 200px html file, I get a 800px blank space underneath and keep the 1000px height.

The goal is to always have the height of the `WKWebView` to adapt to the height of its content.

Here is the current version of the custom render

```cs
namespace MyNamespace.iOS.CustomControl
{
    public class AutoHeightWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);

                if (NativeView != null)
                {
                    var webView = (WKWebView)NativeView;
                    NavigationDelegate = new ExtendedWKWebViewDelegate(this);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log the Exception  
            }   
        }
    }


    class ExtendedWKWebViewDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {

        AutoHeightWebViewRenderer webViewRenderer;

        public ExtendedWKWebViewDelegate(AutoHeightWebViewRenderer _webViewRenderer = null)
        {
            webViewRenderer = _webViewRenderer ?? new AutoHeightWebViewRenderer();
        }

        public override async void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            try
            {
                var _webView = webViewRenderer.Element as AutoHeightWebView;
                if (_webView != null)
                {
                    _webView.HeightRequest = 0d;
                    await Task.Delay(300);
                    var result = await _webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");
                    _webView.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log the Exception 
            }
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT 1 : 
To be clearer, I'm able to change the height of the webview, but I dont know the height because it always returned the height of the largest html displayed so far. Nomatter if I use `_webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()")` or `webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height`.

EDIT 2 :
Here a little sample to help understand the problem. I got two buttons and my custom webview (initialize with a 40 `HeightRequest` empty html).
The first button set the `Source` of the webview to a 70px long HTML. The second one set the `Source` to a 280px long HTML.

[image]

In this example, I click on the first button than the second one and finaly back on the first button again. You see the webview getting bigger on the first 2 clicks. But then then webview should get shrunk when I choose back the first html (passing from 280px to 70px) but it keeps the 280px long.

First button (70px long) 
[image]

Second button (280px long) 
[image]

Back to the first button (should be 70px long instead of 280px).
[image]

The problem occured on both simulator and iOS device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `Frame` of `webView` to change the `height`.

```
public override async void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
{
    try
    {
        var _webView = webViewRenderer.Element as WebView;
        if (_webView != null)
        {

            webView.Frame = new CGRect(webView.Frame.Location, new CGSize(webView.Frame.Size.Width, 0));

            var a = webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height;
            var b = await _webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");

            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(b);

            CGRect tempRect = webView.Frame;

            // for test                    
            webView.Frame = new CGRect(tempRect.Location.X, tempRect.Location.Y, tempRect.Size.Width, float.Parse(b));

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log the Exception 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jack! Thank you for your response. I tried your solution but the problem remains the same. The `(double)webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height` always gives the highest value. I got the same result if I use `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync`. I'm able to change the height of the view with the `HeightRequest`. The problem is that I don't know how long the html is(what the height of it). The height value returned is the height of the largest html displayed in the webview since its creation. In short, I need a way to get the current height of the current html, not the biggest one displayed so far. Thank

Comment: Did you add a break point there to see the value of webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height? The value did change on my side with long or short html content.

Comment: Yes I did. I just tested my custom webview in a separate view with 2 buttons. 1 that changes the source of the webview to a html 200px long and an other button that change the source to a html 100px long. The size is always 200px long. The `webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height` always return the biggest html used. This is happening on a real iPhone device.

Comment: I just updated the post with an example and some screenshots.

Comment: Can you have a try with my updated code to see if it works on your side?

Comment: It works most of the time. I added a task.delay of 300 ms and seems to work all the time!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the CustomNavigationDelegate would also only show the same large size, which was the Device Display size.

I found that I had set this on the init part of the XAML and code behind, which somehow overrides the later content-based calculation.

See my fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62409859/3443564